# AJAX GET Request not sending anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently trying to test out custom headers in `AJAX`, but when i open the `html` file with the `JS` function below, no request is made. `Edge` only says after about 30 seconds that the `Response got loaded from cache`.
Does someone know why that happens?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function load() {
                //$.ajaxSetup({headers: { "CustomHeader": "myValue" }});
                alert("loaded");
            }

            function request() {
                var settings = {
                    "crossDomain": true,
                    "url": "http://localhost:11280/AmbrosiaREST.svc/TestCookie",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "SessionID": "IDNOSET",
                        "UserID": "2",
                        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
                    },
                    "processData": true
                }

                $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }).fail((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                }).always(() => {
                    console.log("sth");
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <button type="button" onclick="request()">Send smth</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You js code is not valid. Is `$.ajax` inside the `request()` function or outside?

Comment: Yes, it is. The whole code is inside the function, notepad++ also marks the correct area EDIT: i think i forgot a `}`

Comment: No, it's not. You forgot the closing `}` for your function.

Comment: I forgot to copy it to stackoverflow, in my .html file the function is valid, i just missed the last line when i copied it.

Comment: "when i open the html file with the JS function below, no request is made" — You never call the `request` function.

Comment: It makes no sense to set a Content-Type on a GET request.

Comment: What status code do you receive? 304?

Comment: EDIT: i posted the full html file
i dont even get a status in edge, only in chrome an `OPTIONS` Request is made

Comment: EDIT: i removed content type, still no request is made

Comment: In chrome the `OPTIONS` Request returns 405, Edge still doesnt do a single Request

Comment: "Edge only says after about 30 seconds that the Response got loaded from cache" - What do you mean by that? if no requests are being sent, how do you receive "Respones got loaded from cache"?

Comment: I have been asking this myself too.

Comment: Is anything being printed in your console?

Comment: The only console output i get is "sth", so the request calls the `always`method, but in the network tab no requests are shown until i get the message that it was loaded from cache EDIT: i changed the `console.log(response)`to `alert(response)` and now i get an alert with `[Object] [Object]` after about 30 seconds

Comment: I removed `async:true,` and i still get the same alert

Comment: this is exactly what you have on the html file? because you have ecma script 6 on that, arrow function doesn't exist on javascript, the console didnt show an error?

Comment: Yes, this is my whole `.html` file

Comment: try replacing fail(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }).always(function() {
                    console.log("sth");
                })

Comment: replace it with what?

Comment: There definitely `must` be something in your `Network` tab. Even I've just received a `console.log` message from `fail` callback and `200` status code in the `Network` tab. Or check your server logs.

Comment: The service traces shows no executed calls, and in the `network` tab in edge i only get "Loaded from cache" after 30 seconds, before that no pending request is listed

Comment: try removing "crossDomain" line

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the HTTP version (1.0, 1.1 etc.) and browsers this should work even for some older such as IE6.

```js
function request() {
  var settings = {
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:11280/AmbrosiaREST.svc/TestCookie",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "SessionID": "IDNOSET",
      "UserID": "2",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
      "Pragma": "no-cache",
      "Expires": 0
    },
    "processData": true
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
  }).fail((response) => {
  console.log("fail");
    console.log(response);
  }).always(() => {
    console.log("sth");
  })
}
request()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Throws `SCRIPT1009: Expected '}'
cookie.html (23,7)` at `Cache-Control` EDIT: added the missing `,` and it compiles now

Comment: But it still didnt change anything

Comment: My bad added the comma

Comment: I did wonder about the `"processData": true` what if you use `"processData": false`